# Parsing emails from JSON data

Tags: python, json, python-2.7

New to programing and Python.  I have been working on this problem for a few days now and I have yet to be able to solve it sadly.  I have gotten so close but still success eludes me...

Here is the raw data I am working with prior to my code. (I get this data from the Twitter API after my code makes the call)

```
{"metadata":{"result_type":"recent","iso_language_code":"et"},"created_at":"Tue Dec 03 01:41:53 +0000 2013","id":407686093790662656,"id_str":"407686093790662656","text":"@emblems123 justinbieberfan12599@gamil.com","source":"\u003ca href=\"http:\/\/twitter.com\/download\/iphone\" rel=\"nofollow\"\u003eTwitter for iPhone\u003c\/a\u003e","truncated":false,"in_reply_to_status_id":407677310821613569,"in_reply_to_status_id_str":"407677310821613569","in_reply_to_user_id":2201997043,"in_reply_to_user_id_str":"2201997043","in_reply_to_screen_name":"emblems123","user":{"id":1220098345,"id_str":"1220098345","name":"PYD","screen_name":"bieberfan12599","location":
```

Below is my code:

```
import csv
import json
import oauth2 as oauth
import urllib
import sys
import requests
import time
import re

CONSUMER_KEY = ""
CONSUMER_SECRET = ""
ACCESS_KEY = ""
ACCESS_SECRET = ""

class TwitterSearch:
    def __init__(self,
        ckey    = CONSUMER_KEY,
        csecret = CONSUMER_SECRET,
        akey    = ACCESS_KEY,
        asecret = ACCESS_SECRET,
        query   = 'https://api.twitter.com/1.1/search/tweets.{mode}?{query}'
    ):
        consumer     = oauth.Consumer(key=ckey, secret=csecret)
        access_token = oauth.Token(key=akey, secret=asecret)
        self.client  = oauth.Client(consumer, access_token)
        self.query   = query

    def search(self, q, mode='json', **queryargs):
        queryargs['q'] = q
        query = urllib.urlencode(queryargs)
        return self.client.request(self.query.format(query=query, mode=mode))

def write_csv(fname, rows, header=None, append=False, **kwargs):
    filemode = 'ab' if append else 'wb'
    with open(fname, filemode) as outf:
        out_csv = csv.writer(outf, **kwargs)
        if header:
            out_csv.writerow(header)
        out_csv.writerows(rows)

def main():
    ts = TwitterSearch()
    response, data = ts.search('@gmail.com', result_type='recent')
    js = json.loads(data)

    messages = ([msg['created_at'], msg['text'], msg['user']['id']] for msg in js.get('statuses', []))
    write_csv('twitter_gmail.csv', messages, append=True)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

It produces data below:

```
Tue Dec 17 19:57:22 +0000 2013,"@soccerdotcom work for DQB-Planning campaign 4 RealMadrid,who should I approach to further discuss this? iturraldedebracamonte@gmail.com",399224668
```

I want it to produce the code below where the email address is extracted from the text and printed instead of the whole message.

```
Tue Dec 17 19:57:22 +0000 2013, "iturraldedebracamonte@gmail.com",399224668
```

I have gotten very close with Regex and splits but I still can't get it right.

Any ideas or what direction I should take would be really helpful.  Can I put a regex into the generator when I am parsing the json?

Comment: It looks like it should be pretty straightforward. How close have you gotten?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do anything that can be put into an expression in your generator expression. The question is more, do you really *want* to?

Say you used a regular expression and `.findall()`:

```
email_re = re.compile(r'<some expression>')

messages = ([msg['created_at'], ' '.join(email_re.findall(msg['text'])), msg['user']['id']] for msg in js.get('statuses', []))
```

This makes your one line of code rather long and unreadable.

I'd factor out the extraction to a function here:

```
def extract_info(msg):
    created_at = msg['created_at']
    user_id = msg['user']
    text = msg['txt']
    emails = email_re.findall(text)
    return (created_at, ' '.join(emails), user_id)

messages = (extract_info(msg) for msg in js.get('statuses', []))
```

Comment: So I had the     string = str(js)
    regex = "\w+@\w+\.com"
    match = re.findall(regex,string) and could get the email matches out of the data but I totally didn't know I could do ' '.join(email_re.findall(msg['text']))  ...that is so much better..

Comment: I also tried for page in js:

        search_terms = ['@gmail.com', '@hotmail.com', '@yahoo.com', '@ymail.com', '@aol.com', '@comcast.net', '@msn.com', '@verizon.net']
        text = str(page.get('text'))
        words = text.split()
        matches = []
        for term in search_terms:
            match = [word for word in words if term in word]
            matches.append(match)
 but since it wasn't an callable object and errored..